# How to interpret received packets, although not being destination host

Tags: linux, man-in-the-middle, arp-spoofing, docker, openssh

Set up:

- Victim: `192.168.0.2`
- Attacker (also having SSH server installed): `192.168.0.3`
- SSH server: `192.168.0.4`

I perform a successful ARP Spoofing attack (being obviously the attacker's MAC address):

[image: victim shell shown]

But when I try to connect via `ssh user@192.168.0.4`, instead of connecting to the attacker's ssh server, it redirects the traffic to the real ssh server (or keeps waiting for this connection if traffic redirect is disabled in attackers `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` file).

Is there any way I could interpret packets coming from an IP before redirecting to the original destination?

Note: in case it's relevant, I'm using Ubuntu docker containers inside GNS3 inside a VM. This is the scheme:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "intercept"? And you are running the `ssh user@192.168.0.4` command from the victim?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to have happen? "instead of connecting to the attacker's ssh server, it redirects the traffic to the real ssh server" -- it sounds like you configured your attacker machine to do this since disabling ip forwarding cuts the connection.

Comment: Ask yourself this: if the packets are still addressed to the original server, why would your attacker machine think they belong to them? You need to create a firewall rule to rewrite the destination.